# unexpected keyword_do_block expecting keyword_end

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to rails and am getting error and not sure why.  Here is the entire error

/Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/book_review/app/views/books/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end ...pend= simple_form_for @book :html => {:multipart => true} ... ... ^ /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/book_review/app/views/books/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end ...tml => {:multipart => true} do |f|@output_buffer.safe_appen... ... ^ /Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/book_review/app/views/books/_form.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Here is the code for the _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @book  :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f|%>
    <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category")%>
    <%= f.file_field :book_img%>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :author %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The error seeks to be looking for keyword end, but I have end at the bottom the the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma at first line:

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f|%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a comma. your first line should read like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f|%>
```